# Remover Hora no campo DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Prezados, preciso apresentar apenas a data em um campo TextBoxFor. Uso esse Controle HTML por que uso uma mascara JavaScript que formata o valor do campo no momento do input da data.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DtCadastro, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "DtCadastro", @name = "DtCadastro", @onkeyup = "javascript:Formatar(this.value, this.form.name, this.name, 'data');", @onchange = "javascript:Formatar(this.value, this.form.name, this.name, 'data');" })


[Display(Name = "Data do Cadastro:")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data do cadastro")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DtCadastro { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de todas é usando apenas:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DtCadastro, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Data de Cadastro" })
```

Não precisa nada daqueles eventos JavaScript que você colocou. Apenas isso resolve.

Comment: Deu certo @Cigano .. Mesmo com a mascara deu certo ..  Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Para esses casos, você pode utilizar um `EditorTemplate`

Crie uma pasta chamada `EditorTemplates` dentro da pasta `Shared`
Crie uma View `DateTime.cshtml`
e coloque:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue && Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "", new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Quando for usar uma propriedade DateTime use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date,"DateTime")
```

A segunda opção é utilizar o próprio `TextBoxFor`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date,string.format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy",Model.Date.Value))
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ocorreu o seguinte erro: "Índice (baseado em zero) deve ser maior ou igual a zero e menor que o tamanho da lista de argumentos". O campo está sendo preenchido com a data do dia no momento do carregamento da View.

Comment: @GleisonFrança qual opção você fez ?

Comment: A ultima, TextBoxFor..

Comment: @GleisonFrança corrigi, é que seu DateTime é nullable, então no string.format tem que ter Model.Date.Value

Comment: infelizmente não deu certo. Fiz vários testes e novamente o erro surgir: "A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto".

Comment: cara, manda como você está fazendo no seu html helper

Comment: Removi os arrobas. segue: 
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DtCadastro, string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy", Model. DtCadastro.Value), htmlAttributes: new { id = "DtCadastro", name = "DtCadastro", onkeyup = "javascript:Formatar(this.value, this.form.name, this.name, 'data');", onchange = "javascript:Formatar(this.value, this.form.name, this.name, 'data');" })

Comment: Essa resposta é quase a certa. Só sinto que você complicou um pouco.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu passei o que ele queria saber, formatação da data usando o HtmlHelper, porém, ele possui mais atributos do seu próprio input...